# Two pattern match on same sed command

Tags: linux, sed

I have the following sed command:

```
sed -n '/^out(/{n;p}' ${filename} | sed -n '/format/ s/.*format=//g; s/),$//gp; s/))$//gp'
```

I tried to do it as one line as in:

```
sed -n '/^out(/{n;}; /format/ s/.*format=//g; s/),$//gp; s/))$//gp' ${filename}
```

But that also display the lines I don't want (those that do not match).

What I have is a file with some strings as in:

```
entry(variable=value)),
format(variable=value)),
entry(variable=value)))
out(variable=value)),
format(variable=value)),
...
```

I just want the format lines that came right after the out entry. and remove those trailing )) or ),

Comment: I know that I can do it with grep, but I want to use a single command  with a single execution (or a single grep, single awk or single sed. And for that I thought that sed would have smaller memory/cpu footprint.

Comment: the second sed command in your question works perfectly for the sample input you have given.

Comment: @Lin It would be easier for all if you put up sample input & output required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this sed command:

```
sed -nr '/^out[(]/ {n ; s/.*[(]([^)]+)[)].*/\1/p}' your_file
```

Once a `out` is found, it advanced to the next line (`n`) and uses the `s` command with `p` flag to extract only what is inside parenthesises.

Explanation:

- I used `[(]` instead of `\(`. Outside brackets a `(` usually means grouping, if you want a literal `(`, you need to escape it as `\(` or you can put it inside brackets. Most RE special characters dont need escaping when put inside brackets.
- `([^)]+)` means a group (the "(" here are RE metacharacters not literal parenthesis) that consists of one or more (`+`) characters that are not (`^`) `)` (literal closing parenthesis), the `^` inverts the character class `[ ... ]`

Comment: Seems promissing =D just changing out for ^out, because I can find the out word inside some variable/value.

Comment: Your response fits perfect to the data  I have provided above. (that I now noticed that isn't exactly my original source data). But is ok. I have made the necessary corrections to fit my real data.

Comment: @Lin changed the pattern between the `/../`

Comment: Why do you encapsulate the ( with [] ?

What does the ^) after the group opening ( ?

Comment: @Lin I tried to explain it a bit more in detail. for more information about regular expressions, you could start at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean/22944075#22944075